# Weird issue with ip routing on loopback interface

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

This question is based on my failed attempt to get the famous tool `fragroute` working in my environment.

**Problem description:**

I have a ubuntu OS 18.04 host with an (Intel) ethernet interface `enp1s0f1` which is used for sending/receiving test traffic. I tried to develop an app that can modify the outgoing packets from this interface to destination IP address 10.200.1.2. I added the following route so that the outgoing packet will be sent to loopback `lo` interface which my app can sniff with libpcap, the the app will then modify the packets and send it out with the test interface `enp1s0f1`

```
ip route add 10.200.1.2 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
```

After adding this route, the routing table has a new route (from the output of `ip route show`)

```
10.200.1.2 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
```

The problem is, if I send tcp SYN packets from 10.200.1.3 to 10.200.2.2 at server port 23, the linux correctly responds with TCP RST. If I send TCP SYN packet from 10.200.1.2 to 10.200.2.2, linux tcp/ip doesn't respond with TCP SYN packet as if it doesn't see it, here is the tcpdump on interface `enp1s0f1`.

```
17:23:18.393222 IP 10.200.1.3.37063 > 10.200.2.2.23: Flags [S], seq 2933924869, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4013600474 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:23:18.393236 IP 10.200.2.2.23 > 10.200.1.3.37063: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2933924870, win 0, length 0
17:23:22.080899 IP 10.200.1.2.40109 > 10.200.2.2.23: Flags [S], seq 1253688325, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1468392057 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:23:23.107692 IP 10.200.1.2.40109 > 10.200.2.2.23: Flags [S], seq 1253688325, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1468393084 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:23:23.395478 ARP, Request who-has 10.200.1.3 tell 10.200.2.2, length 28
17:23:23.395494 ARP, Request who-has 10.200.2.2 tell 10.200.1.2, length 46
17:23:23.395544 ARP, Reply 10.200.1.3 is-at a0:36:9f:54:25:24, length 46
```

This difference is clearly related to the newly added route, but I don't know why, after all, routing should not come to picture once the packet arrives at the interface with the matching IP.

By the way, I also used tcpdump to check packets with tcp port 23 on the loopback interface `lo`, there are no such packets. This further indicates that it's likely that the linux TCP/IP stack don't see the TCP syn packet from 10.200.1.2.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to this problem with the help of [this blog](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/rp_filter-and-lpic-3-linux-security/).

After running the following command, the tcp session from the special IP can get processed.

```
ip netns exec pcapReplay1 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
ip netns exec pcapReplay1 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
ip netns exec pcapReplay1 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0f1.rp_filter=0
ip netns exec pcapReplay1 sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter=0
```